# How to call a function after wordpress page/post load?

Tags: php, wordpress

<strike>I'm trying invoke a function after wordpress page/post load. I added:</strike>

```
add_action('wp_loaded','MyFunc');
```

to functions.php but it's not working. How do I do that correctly?

Edit:
So I'm going in a different way, I put

```
<script>
          MyFunc();
</script>
<input class="clickMe" type="button" value="call MyFunc" onclick="MyFunc();" />
```

at the end of comments.php
The button works great and when I press it, the function is called.
But I want the function to run without pressing the button. and that doesn't work.

Comment: You can't use PHP to run a function after page load, because PHP is a server-side language. What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: Admin side or frontend?

Comment: Oh... I understand, thank you.
I have a function that loads only 20 comments and i want it to run automatically after the page/post loads. On the frontend

Answer (score 5):

Use the footer hook.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'your_function');
```

or

```
add_action('get_footer', 'your_function');
```

make sure either do_action('wp_footer') or wp_footer() is called in your theme/ on your page.

Also make sure your function `echo`s or `return`s something.

Comment: This isn't really "after page load"...unless the OP meant "after the post content is rendered"...

Comment: I already have "add_action('wp_footer', 'your_function');" in functions.php file. and i also have "<input  type="button" value="load comments" onclick="your_function();" />" at the end of comments.php file. I just want this function to run without having to press the button.

Comment: @mevius I assumed comments were meant to show up between content and footer. That is the most logical thing to do.

OP, you are mixing two approaches: use jQuery/Javascript and using PHP. I think in this case PHP is easier, unless you want the visitor to decide whether to see the comments or not.

Does your function return anything? Can you show your code?

Comment: The function doesn't return anything. Every time the function runs, it loads 20 more comments (because some of my pages have hundreds of comments). The button works great, every time I press it, I get 20 more comments. But I want the first batch of 20 comments to show automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, I added a script after the button:

```
<input class="clickMe" type="button" value="call MyFunc" onclick="MyFunc();" />
<script>
  onload = function() {
    MyFunc()
  }
</script>
```